# Find the product of no real roots of $P(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)=x^5+b^2x-c^2$ be, with $bc\neq0$,$b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $P(a)=0$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Find the product of nonreal roots of $P(x)$.

My attempt:
I know that $a^5+b^2a-c^2=0$ and for Cardano, $r_1r_2r_3r_4=\frac{c}{a}$ and $r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=-a$.

I want to know which of $r_1,r_2,r_3$ and $r_4$ are imaginary, but I don't know what else to do.

Please Help me.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti I'm sorry my English is not so good. And yes, I meant product of roots that are not real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P'(x)=5x^4+b^2\ge b^2 >0$$

There is only one real root which is $a$.

Hence $$r_1r_2r_3r_4=\frac{c^2}a$$